# Could not open genesis config file

Tags: rust, indexer, nearprotocol

I am just following the instruction: https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/chain/indexer/README.md
to setup testnet indexer. The command `cargo run --release --home-dir ~/.near/testnet init --chain-id testnet --download` that was suggested to run in the instruction doesn't work, it seems that we should replace it -> `cargo run --release -- --home-dir ~/.near/testnet init --chain-id testnet --download`
Then, as it was described in the instruction I modified config file to adjust shards.
Then run the command: `cargo run --release -- --home-dir ~/.near/testnet/ run` and receive:

```
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.51s
     Running `/Users/bohdan_malkevych/Documents/me/git/near-protocol/nearcore/target/release/indexer-example --home-dir /Users/bohdan_malkevych/.near/testnet/ run`
thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not open genesis config file.: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', /Users/bohdan_malkevych/Documents/me/git/near-protocol/nearcore/core/chain-configs/src/genesis_config.rs:216:37
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I have checked `/.near/testnet/` folder and can't find any genesis files there.
What I did wrong? Where I can find this genesis file?

OS: Mac OS

Answer (score 5):

Codeowner of NEAR Indexer is here.

Thanks for pointing of missing `--` in README. I'm fixing it.

As for your problem you can download `genesis.json` from the link https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/build.nearprotocol.com/nearcore-deploy/testnet/genesis.json (it was posted in Discord https://discord.com/channels/490367152054992913/708278589031710761/762954092703907850)

`init` command should have downloaded `genesis.json`. It might fail downloading if you already have the directory you've provided to `--home-dir` and there is something placed.

(I have checked `init` before writing this answer `cargo run -- --home-dir ~/.near/test_init/ init --chain-id testnet --download` and it has downloaded `genesis.json` along with other necessary files)

Also using `run` command try to remove trailing slash from `--home-dir` like so

```
cargo run --release -- --home-dir ~/.near/testnet run
```

You can try to start over by removing your `~/.near/testnet` and running `init` command again.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading manually (wget or curl, or whichever tool you prefer) the genesis file:

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/build.nearprotocol.com/nearcore-deploy/testnet/genesis.json

and put it into the home folder (~/.near/testnet)

Comment: After that I have got such view: INFO stats: #18819727 Waiting for peers 0/0/40 peers 0 B/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 1%, Mem: 5.1 Gib fro a long time